# undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, fedora

I'm working on a git project (c++), until this afternoon, everything was fine. I could compile without any problem. (I should point out that I work under Fedora 29) A major change in cmake took place earlier. My version of cmake that I was using was then apparently no longer sufficient. So I had to update my cmake (something I had never done before, and apparently I had to do wrong.... First, I made:

```
sudo dnf remove cmake
```

Then I installed the latest version of cmake directly for download on the official website https://cmake.org/download/ (3.13.1)

Okay, the installation apparently went well. cmake 3.13.1 works...

Now I'm trying to recompile the project and then this error appears

```
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/lib64/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/lib64/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
```

Here, is the more complete error:

```
 [ 69%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../../Build/bin/DecimaterGui
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/lib64/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/lib64/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make[5]: *** [src/OpenMesh/Apps/Decimating/DecimaterGui/CMakeFiles/DecimaterGui.dir/build.make:192: Build/bin/DecimaterGui] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:814: src/OpenMesh/Apps/Decimating/DecimaterGui/CMakeFiles/DecimaterGui.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenMesh.dir/build.make:111: OpenMesh-prefix/src/OpenMesh-stamp/OpenMesh-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/OpenMesh.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

The problem is that when I did

```
sudo dnf remove cmake
```

I went too fast, and I probably deleted other packets that were useful... Apparently, dnf also deletes dependent packets...  I think that's where the problem comes from, but that's just a hypothesis...

I don't know if it's really useful but in the project, we use other git projects as sub-modules (like OpenMesh, Assimp...). If I just make a make, the error appears with OpenMesh (precisely the bin DecimaterGui). But if I compile with make -j 4, the error also appears with other libraries (and other bin).

I may have searched the Internet, but I couldn't find any solutions. Or at least the solution to my problem. So, if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be really cool!

I hope I was quite precise and that my English was sufficiently clear. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You must've uninstalled libuuid-devel, try reinstalling it:

```
dnf install libuuid-devel
```