# opencv c++ fails the make -j4

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc

I'm trying to install `OpenCV` in `c++` locally on my machine with `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LST` following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-opencv-in-c-on-linux/) manual.

The first two steps went good, but I'm stuck on the `make -j4` substep of the third step. Running this command results in the following error message:

```
[ 83%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_highgui
[ 83%] Built target opencv_test_calib3d
[ 83%] Built target opencv_perf_objdetect
[ 83%] Built target opencv_test_objdetect
[ 83%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
[ 83%] Built target opencv_test_stitching
[ 83%] Built target opencv_perf_video
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_gapi
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_interactive-calibration
[ 83%] Built target opencv_test_video
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/calibController.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/calibPipeline.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to `uuid_parse@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to `uuid_generate_random@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to `uuid_unparse@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so: undefined reference to `uuid_copy@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/build.make:122: bin/opencv_test_highgui] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2958: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/frameProcessor.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/api/grunarg.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/parametersController.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/rotationConverters.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/api/gorigin.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/api/gmat.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/api/garray.cpp.o
[ 83%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_interactive-calibration
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642640/undefined-reference-to-uuid-generateuuid-1-0) answer to get the missing libraries, but as I see its for the `red hat`, and I need it for `Ubuntu`.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are in need of the `uuid-dev` package. Try running:

```
sudo apt install uuid-dev
```